# Applescript to duplicate file from mounted volume to desktop

Tags: applescript

I am just getting starteded with Applescript and need some help with a simple file copy from a Windows server.  I am mounting a volume to a Windows share and I need to copy the files from that folder to the desktop.  Here's the AppleScript I have so far.

```
tell application "Finder"
   mount volume "smb://username:password@server.domain.com/source/MAC/StandardApps"
   duplicate file "SymantecEndpointProtection.zip" of folder "StandardApps" to    folder "Desktop"
end tell
```

The error I get is "Can't set folder \"Desktop\" to folder \"StandardApps\"."

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, again I'm new to Applescript.  Grateful for any help.  I will provide any additional info you need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `to folder "Desktop"` to `to desktop`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the complete file paths.  For example, the path to the desktop folder in your user's account can be found by using **path to desktop folder**.  Another easy way to see what a file path is would be to look at the result from a **choose file** dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by just mounting to the source share and changing the duplicate line to:

```
duplicate file "SymantecEndPointProtection.zip" of folder "StandardApps" of folder "Mac" of disk "source" to folder desktopPath
```